# MVC IP address data anotation gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC data annotations for IP address validation but getting below error although IP given in Correct (192.168.1.118)  Invalid IP format or internal/private IP cannot be saved

Code in JS

```
Var abc = Sys.Mvc.FormContext.getValidationForForm(form).validate('submit');
```

Code in 
Form.CS file:

```
[IPAddress]
[DisplayLabel("PageContent", "lblIPAddressFrom")]
public string IPAddressFrom { get; set; }
```

Comment: Isn't 192.168.*.* an internal address and the error message says `.. or internal/private IP cannot be saved`?

Comment: Yes it is internal IP and it says  Invalid IP format or internal/private IP cannot be saved #Soner Gönül

Comment: Are you accessing your site using http://localhost/ adress? If so, your ip adress won't be defined.

Comment: I mean it will be defined but might be different from what you expect. (127.0.0.1 or maybe even ::1 with ipv6)

Comment: Yes i am accessing using localhost but problem is while logging in it saves the data DB but when I am retrieving the data from DB then this IP address data annotation is being used and returns the error message can you please advice for what it will validate i mean which format or size..??

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression for  IPv4;

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$")]
public string IPAddressFrom { get; set; }
```